# Prove that $f$ in invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $M \in F^{nxn}$ be an upper $nxn$ triangular matrix, namely $m_{ij}=0$ if $ 1 ≤ j < i ≤ n$.

(i) Suppose that $m_{ii} \neq 0$ for all $1 ≤ i ≤ n$. Prove that $f_M: F^{n} \to F^{n}$ is invertible.

(ii)  Suppose that $m_{ii} = 0$ for some $1 ≤ i ≤ n$. Prove that $f_M: F^{n} \to F^{n}$ is not one-to-one.

(iii) Suppose that $m_{ii} = 0$ for some $1 ≤ i ≤ n$. Prove that $f_M: F^{n} \to F^{n}$ is not onto.

In this question, I can understand and see all the assumptions above, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to write it mathematically and make a good proof.

(i) For the first problem, we may rewrite the funcion $f_M: F^{n} \to F^{n}$  as $f_M=M*x$. So to prove that the function is one-to-one we should prove that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$.

Then, $M*x=M*y$

But from here, it isn't actually clear the path that I am supposed to take to make a proper proof.

Let $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$

And $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_N)$

Therefore, we must have after the matrix vector multiplication the following system of equations

$M_{11}x_1+M_{12}x_2+\ldots+M_{1N}x_N=M_{11}y_1+M_{12}y_2+\ldots+M_{1N}y_N$

.

.

.

$M_{NN}*x_N=M_{NN}*y_N$

So that, from last equation, $X_N=Y_N$ since $M_{NN} \neq 0$

And doing that, we are going to get that every $x_{i}=y_{i}$ So the function is one-to-one.

For the surjectivity,$f(x)=F=M*x$ we are supposed to prove that for every $F$ we can find a solution for $x$. And in this moment, I think I can prove that the columns of the matrix can form a basis for $F^{n}$ so it can generate any value of $F$ in $F^n$, so that it is proved the function is onto.

I was wondering if this solution is good, or if there's another way of doing it in a better way. I mean, since we can interpret those matrices as functions, is there any way of proving injectivity without the system of equations, just using the functions? What about surjectivity, is this proof valid?

Comment: Can you use determinants?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use it at this moment

Comment: For $(ii)$ and $(iii)$  show that the first $i$ columns are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

For (i), just rewrite more carefully your proof that $f$ is one-to-one, showing that given $y=(y_1,\dots,y_N),$ your system of $N$ equations not only has *at most* one solution $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$ but *exactly* one.

For (ii), choose $y=(0,\dots,0)$ and solve your system similarily. If $i$ is the greatest index for which $m_{i,i}=0,$ You will get successively $x_N=0,\dots,x_{i+1}=0$, then no constraint on $x_i$ (and then $x_{i-1},\dots,x_1$ depending on the choice you made for $x_i$). So several $x$'s are sent by $f_M$ to the same $y.$

For (iii), if (again) $i$ is the greatest index for which $m_{i,i}=0,$ show that for $y=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ where the $1$ is at the $i$'th place, your system has no solution.